# Why am I getting: undefined method `primary_key' for Hash:Class using invite! when inviting users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, devise-invitable

I have a rails app with devise

I have hooked up devise_invitable gem as well and did the config

In my create admin controller, I'm calling the invite! method but I'm getting an error and can't seem to understand why.

in creation action in controller

```
admin.invite!(email: "kellenwesley1@gmail.com", name: "John Doe")
```

output from rails:

"undefined method `primary_key' for Hash:Class"

Any idea why? I can't solve.

Comment: what is the value of `admin`?

Answer (score 0):

This is occurring because you are calling `invite!` on an instance of a class rather than the class itself.   Assuming the class is called `Admin` you should change it to:

```
Admin.invite!(email: "kellenwesley1@gmail.com", name: "John Doe")
```